# Sell by date of 4/17/19

Tags: chicken

I have frozen chicken cutlets beaded with parmasean cheese and a sell by date of 4/17/19 can they still by cooked and eaten?

Comment: Who froze them? When? Sell by is not consume by.

Comment: Do you mean breaded?

Answer (score 3):

The "[Sell by](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2015/04/150415203336.htm)" date is aimed at retailers and indicates the date by which a product should be sold, or removed from the shelf. In many countries, such as the UK, there are no sell-by dates, as consumers found them confusing. There could be as much as 1/3 of the shelf life of the product remaining.

Best-before dates are indicative. The quality of the food may have deteriorated but it should still be safe to eat after the best before date.

Use-by dates are concerned with food safety. Food should be consumed before the use-by date, or discarded. The food may still be safe to eat after the use-by date, but if you get sick, then it will be harder to successfully sue the manufacturer.

Provided the chicken has been constantly frozen in deep freeze (-18 ⁰C) it should still be safe to eat after the "sell by" date.